How to deal with not continuous stock price data?
I have stock price dataset as below:
Date/Time       Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
12/22/2020 9:15 83.8    83.8    83.8    83.8    5110
12/22/2020 9:16 83.8    83.8    83.7    83.7    1200
12/22/2020 9:17 83.7    83.7    83.6    83.6    910
12/22/2020 9:18 83.1    83.1    83      83      9800
12/22/2020 9:19 82.9    83      82.9    83      1140
12/22/2020 9:20 83      83      82.8    82.9    9130
12/22/2020 9:21 83      83      83      83      1000

Data in 1 minute time step, I need build LSTM model to predict stock fluctuations with stock fluctuations  = stock after N(N is minute, hour or day) - stock now.
Problem is only have data from 09:00 to 15:00 of each day, how I deal with this data?
Any help is appreciated.

This is a problem solving issue, not a programming question. You might get better answers to your question if you repost over at the Cross Validated StackExchange.
